# Seeking model builder for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Like the ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Desktop to run simultaneous geoprocessing tools, is there any model builder available in QGIS?

Comment: I am glad to inform that we are currently working on SEXTANTE for QGIS. It should be ready soon, and it will include the modeler, which is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 16):

[Sextante](http://sextantegis.com/) is a geoprocessing library that can be used from several GIS applications. I recommend you to use it from [gvSIG](http://www.gvsig.org/web/plugins/downloads/gvsig-1-11-portable) as i think that it has the best integration. Sextante also allows (if you configure it properly) use algorithms from SAGA and GRASS.

Here you can see [a video that shows how the modeler works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvm_zV9nr3U&list=UUhxDtM3siarv_3l5I9_UMxA&index=24&feature=plcp).

Update: From March, [qgis also has a Sextante plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sextante/) that works really well.

Comment: Sextante plugin is now core in the recent versions of QGIS and is called "Processing"

Answer (score 15):

**GRASS** has a model builder that works pretty well (don't know how it compares to the Arc* one).

Victor Olaya, the developer of **Sextante** is currently working on [Sextante for **QGIS**](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sextante/). It's work-in-progress and not yet ready for production use so use with care. You can watch a short demonstration of the Sextante model builder here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTUu-I2ouqU

**Update Nov 2012**: Sextante for QGIS is developing very well, as you can see eg. in this new case study: http://www.qgis.org/en/community/qgis-case-studies/pinhel-portugal.html

**Update Jan 2016**: Sextante is now a core plugin in QGIS recent versions, and it's called Processing. Check more information about in the [QGIS Users Manual - QGIS processing framework](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/index.html). You can also get information about how to use the Graphical Modeler in [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html).

Comment: Publishing such models as Web Processing Services (WPS) would also be good to have in the QGIS RoadMap if it is not there already.

Comment: QGIS offers a WPS client extension. See also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg2pb_Xjq8Y

Comment: See here for the GRASS GIS Model builder: http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Modeler

Answer (score 15):

Now you can access a model builder in QGIS from  the:

**Processing menu -> Graphical modeler**

Answer (score 1):

You may also consider some basic Python scripting to run multiple commands in series.

Comment: Thanks. I am pretty new to QGIS and scripting. All I need to get done is .. enter a value for a polygon and which give me the list of all polygon values adjoining ...Kind of proximity analysis.Any ideas on this...

Comment: IN GRASS (and so in QGIS trough the QGIS/GRASS plugin) you can do proximity analysis, but this does mean you need a model builder.