# Setting "Always run in foreground" within ArcPy code?

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, geoprocessing-framework

Is it possible to set the "Always run in foreground" option within ArcPy code? I haven't found anything on this yet?

It would be nice to be able to specify within a script, instead of through the Geoprocessing Options window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done in ArcPy when you are [Defining a tool in a Python toolbox](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-a-tool-in-a-python-toolbox.htm) by using the `canRunInBackground` property:

> If canRunInBackground is unset or set to True, the tool will respect
>   the current Background Processing setting in the Geoprocessing Options
>   dialog.
>
> If set to False, the tool will always run in the foreground, overriding the Background Processing setting in the Geoprocessing
>   Options dialog.