# How arcMap tool run in async mode with arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I am using python in arcmap 10.0 to execute "Topo To Raster" tool. I am successful to execute this in blocking/sync mode. but I want to execute this tool with python in async mode.

```
workspacePath = sys.argv[1] 
input = sys.argv[2]
output = sys.argv[3]    
arcpy.TopoToRaster_3d(input,output)
```

Comment: have you looked into [Background Geoprocessing](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm)?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you are after is [Background Geoprocessing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000003q000000), which was introduced at ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

However, I *think* ArcPy only became "Background Geoprocessing aware" with the introduction of Python Toolboxes at 10.1 - see [Setting "Always run in foreground" within ArcPy code?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171459/setting-always-run-in-foreground-within-arcpy-code)