# Sharing toolbox with Python script tool for ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arctoolbox

I have a toolbox (several different parameters) that I created using a python script. The tool is meant to be run in ArcMap.

In short, how do I share this tool with other people?

I tried to read online how to do this and not really getting anywhere.

Does it need to be shared via ArcGIS Online?

Is there a way to simply zip up the tool and email it to folks or put it on a shared web-space like Box?

Comment: You need pure text version of toolbox, or it might not work for different arcgis versions https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62839/why-learn-use-python-toolboxes-over-python-script-tools

Comment: Otherwise you can just import the Python script into the toolbox then pass around the .tbx like any other file.

Comment: is a .tbx file the little red toolbox files that say "Arc GIS Toolbox" as file type?  Thanks.

Comment: And when you say 'pass around' - can it simply be zipped and shared via email?  I have imported the python script into the toolbox, I think (by "adding python script").  Are these self contained tools and can simply be emailed, sharepoint, etc?

Answer (score 0):

To do this see [A quick tour of sharing custom tools](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/sharing-workflows/a-quick-tour-of-sharing-tools.htm) in the Online Help for ArcMap:

> You can share geoprocessing results as a package or as a service. When
> you share a result, ArcGIS makes a copy of your model and script
> tools, examines their contents, and makes changes to the copy to
> ensure that the tool will execute on another computer. In addition,
> the data that was used to create the result is also shared.
>
> But what if you want to share your custom tools and not share any
> data? That is, you want to give someone your toolbox and have them use
> the tools within, just as they would with a system toolbox? You can do
> this, but it requires some skill on your part ...